# How to refactor two React components that share near identical logic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two components `DateTimeFormField` and `TimeFormField` that I am trying to refactor because both components share almost identical logic and output.

One approach that I thought of doing was to maybe export the functions inside the functional component `DateTimeFormField` but that doesn't seem to be a clean solution since identical logic will still exist between both components (the declared variables).

From some research, it seems that custom hooks could possibly address the code duplication here but both components are stateless so I'm not entirely sure if a custom hook would be overkill for this type of situation in my case.

DateTimeFormField.tsx

```js
function DateTimeFormField({
    fieldName,
    flatFieldName,
    validationMessage,
    value,
    onChange,
    onBlur
}: FieldProps) {
    const valueAsStr = value === undefined ?
        "" :
        value as string;
    const dateFromValue = valueAsStr.substring(0, 10);
    const timeFromValue = valueAsStr.substring(11, 16);

    const todayDateObj = new Date();
    const todayDate = todayDateObj.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    function onDateChange(dateUpdate: string) {
        const date = dateUpdate || "0000-00-00";
        const time = timeFromValue || "00:00";

        return onChange(flatFieldName, date + "T" + time + ":00+00:00");
    }

    function onTimeChange(timeUpdate: string) {
        const date = dateFromValue || todayDate;
        const time = timeUpdate || "00:00";

        return onChange(flatFieldName, date + "T" + time + ":00+00:00");
    }

    function onTimeBlur(timeUpdate: string, fieldName: string) {
        onTimeChange(timeUpdate);
        onBlur(fieldName);
    }

    return (
        <FormGroup
            validationMessage={validationMessage}
            data-element="date-time-form-field-form-group">
            <FieldLabel fieldName={fieldName} />
            <div className="date-time-combo">
                <DatePicker
                    inputProps={{"data-element": "date-form-field-input"}}
                    dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
                    initialValue={dateFromValue}
                    onChange={(date) => onDateChange(date.isoFormattedDate)}
                    onBlur={() => onBlur(flatFieldName)}
                />
                <TimePicker
                    data-element="time-form-field-input"
                    timeFormat="HH:mm"
                    initialValue={timeFromValue}
                    onSelect={(time) => onTimeChange(time.rawValue)}
                    onBlur={(time) => onTimeBlur(time.rawValue, flatFieldName)}
                />
            </div>
        </FormGroup>
    );
}

export default memo(DateTimeFormField);
```

TimeFormField.tsx

```js
function TimeFormField({
    fieldName,
    flatFieldName,
    validationMessage,
    value,
    onChange,
    onBlur
}: FieldProps) {
    const valueAsStr = value === undefined ?
        "" :
        value as string;
    const dateFromValue = valueAsStr.substring(0, 10);
    const timeFromValue = valueAsStr.substring(11, 16);

    const todayDateObj = new Date();
    const todayDate = todayDateObj.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    function onTimeChange(timeUpdate: string) {
        const date = dateFromValue || todayDate;
        const time = timeUpdate || "00:00";

        return onChange(flatFieldName, date + "T" + time + ":00+00:00");
    }

    function onTimeBlur(timeUpdate: string, fieldName: string) {
        onTimeChange(timeUpdate);
        onBlur(fieldName);
    }

    return (
        <FormGroup
            validationMessage={validationMessage}
            data-element="time-form-field-form-group">
            <FieldLabel fieldName={fieldName} />
            <div className="time-combo">
                <TimePicker
                    data-element="time-form-field-input"
                    timeFormat="HH:mm"
                    initialValue={timeFromValue}
                    onSelect={(time) => onTimeChange(time.rawValue)}
                    onBlur={(time) => onTimeBlur(time.rawValue, flatFieldName)}
                />
            </div>
        </FormGroup>
    );
}

export default memo(TimeFormField);
```

Comment: Create a typescript module and import the functionality from that module. No React magic is necessary.

Comment: Do the two slightly different outputs matter in certain situations or are you basically trying to simplify it down so that you only have one output but either name for the function can be called so that you don't have to hunt down every usage of it in the code base and replace it? Essentially turning the function names into aliases for the same piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a prop that specifies whether or not you want the date to be chosen. Then you can conditionally render based on that prop.

The general form is just

```js
if (/* some condition based on the props*/) {
    return (
        <> something </>
    );
} else {
    return (
        <> something else </>
    );
}
```

But you can also embed the conditional parts into a single `return` statement.

For example, if you add `includeDate: boolean` to your props in the `DateTimeFormField` component, you could render this:

```js
const dataElement = `${includeDate ? "date-" : ""}time-form-field-form-group`;
const divClass = `${includeDate ? "date-" : ""}time-combo`;

return (
    <FormGroup
        validationMessage={validationMessage}
        data-element={dataElement}
    >
        <FieldLabel fieldName={fieldName} />
        <div className={divClass}>
            { includeDate ? (
                <DatePicker
                    inputProps={{"data-element": "date-form-field-input"}}
                    dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
                    initialValue={dateFromValue}
                    onChange={(date) => onDateChange(date.isoFormattedDate)}
                    onBlur={() => onBlur(flatFieldName)}
                />
            ) : null }
            <TimePicker
                data-element="time-form-field-input"
                timeFormat="HH:mm"
                initialValue={timeFromValue}
                onSelect={(time) => onTimeChange(time.rawValue)}
                onBlur={(time) => onTimeBlur(time.rawValue, flatFieldName)}
            />
        </div>
    </FormGroup>
);
```

So you just have one component and render what you want to render based on the props.